# Convert azure synapse notebooks [in json] to python or jupyter

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-notebooks

Local / IDE based development allows use of the most powerful IDE's [`pycharm` in particuilar].  How can the notebooks presently in json format in our git repo be converted to jupyter/ipynb and/or python *on the local environment*.  We have many notebooks and doing so manually by *export* on synapse directly is too tedious/time consuming and is also not repeatable.

Is there any mechanism /command line tool to perform the conversions?